# Stroupstrup Graphics Library Errors

Tags: c++, graphics, fltk

I'm new to *C++* and in my Intro to programming design and concepts class we're now on graphics. I've been able to make programs with just *FLTK*'s library but we have to use Bjarne's library such as `GUI.h`, `Graph.h`, `Simple_window.h`, `Point.h`. A simple program like a simple window program won't compile and gives a usual response of:

```
Simple_window.h:17: error: reference to ‘Window’ is ambiguous
```

I have also tried compiling using:

```
fltk-config --compile main.cpp
```

This yields the same results.

I have tried running the make file that Bjarne has provided with in the folder but that always comes up with errors and makes no `.o` files.

Note: I have also tried compiling on mac *OSX* and *Ubuntu*.

Comment: @chris: No, he isn't involved with FLTK, as far as I'm aware.  But in his book, "Programming Principles and Practice using C++", he uses it. And he wrote his own helper files to simplify the process of using it. http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Well that clears it up, thanks.

Comment: Hush be-careful. Bjarne Stroustrup is on Stackoverflow and he might actually see this question.

Answer (score 6):

I never used either of those libraries, but I saw that tutorials for FLTK always begin with `using namespace fltk;` statement, which imports all FLTK classes, including `fltk::Window` to the root namespace.

The library by B. Stroustrup is contained in namespace called `Graph_lib` and it also has a class called `Window`.
Now, the file `Simple_window.h` has `using namespace Graph_lib;` statement at the beginning, which imports `Graph_lib::Window` to the root namespace. And this is where the ambiguity is coming from.

So I would suggest to omit the `using` statement (at least from `using namespace fltk`) and to use FLTK classes with full specification (e.g. `fltk::Window` instead of just `Window`). This should solve the ambiguity.

As a side note, this is nice example, why having `using namespace` at file level in a header file is a bad idea.

References:
http://www.fltk.org/doc-2.0/html/index.html
http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/Simple_window.h

**EDIT**: I tried to compile the library containing `Simple_window` myself and, at least under linux, it the ambiguity seems to be between class `Graph_lib::Window` from the library and typedef `Window` from xlib as well. xlib is C library and you can't really do anything about it, so you will have to get rid of `using namespace Graph_lib` in Stroustup's library.

In the file `Simple_window.h`:

- delete `using namespace Graph_lib;`
- change `Window` to `Graph_lib::Window`
- `Button` to `Graph_lib::Button`
- and `Address` to `Graph_lib::Address`

Then in the file `Simple_window.cpp`:

- change `Address` to `Graph_lib::Address` again
- and `reference_to<Simple_window>` to `Graph_lib::reference_to<Simple_window>`

Then it should compile. If you have different version than the one that's on stroustrup.com, you may need to fully qualify (add `Graph_lib::`) more classes.

Comment: It's really weird, I just tried to test out a program with nothing in the main function. The ambiguity problems seem to be coming from the header files. It seems like there should be a way to compile the source code of the headers or something.

Comment: Also just tried compiling each cpp files which corresponded with the header files and one out of 4 of them compiled. Something like
>g++ -o Simple_window.o Simple_window.cpp 
is riddled with tons of errors of wrong references. Do I need to place them in a certain folder?

Comment: I see. It's clashing with `Xlib` as well. I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: unfortunately none of this solves the issues mentioned in original post

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same kind of problems (unresolved external symbols) using `Simple_window.h` and trying to compile a the following peace of code:

```
    int main(){

    // create a reference point for the window
    Point topLeft(50,50);
    // initialize a Simple_window object to size: 600x400 pixels, labeled: My window
    Simple_window myWindow(topLeft, 600, 400, "My window");
    // pass control to GUI 
    myWindow.wait_for_button();

    return 0;
    }
```

The solution was to add to the project (along with the `main.cpp`) all the respective `.cpp` files of the included `.h` files:(`"Graph.h"`, `"Window.h"`, `"Simple_window.h"`, `"GUI.h"`)