# Error compiling Stroustrup's graphics library

Tags: c++

I am trying to run an example program from Stroustrup's Principles and Practices using C++, which uses Bjarne's [library](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/PPP2code/) such as, `Simple_window.h`,`Graph.h`,`Point.h`. It throws a slew of errors. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606097/stroupstrup-graphics-library-errors) helped fix an ambiguity with a function `Window`, but still lot of the errors persists.

```
#include "Simple_window.h"
#include "Graph.h"
int main()
{
    using namespace Graph_lib;   // our graphics facilities are in Graph_lib

Point tl(100,100);           // to become top left  corner of window

Simple_window win(tl,600,400,"Canvas");    // make a simple window

Polygon poly;                // make a shape (a polygon)

poly.add(Point(300,200));    // add a point
poly.add(Point(350,100));    // add another point
poly.add(Point(400,200));    // add a third point 

poly.set_color(Color::red);  // adjust properties of poly

win.attach (poly);           // connect poly to the window

win.wait_for_button();       // give control to the display engine
}
```

It then throws the following error

```
    In file included from GUI.h:11:0,
                 from Simple_window.h:2,
                 from first.cpp:7:
Graph.h:159:25: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘fl_color()’ from ‘Fl_Color {aka unsigned int}’ to ‘int’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
  Color lcolor {fl_color()};
```

I compiled it with g++, the OS is Linux Mint.

Comment: @Marc Not sure -- the error looks as if the ctor only takes a single param. Edit: oh, it's the declaration -- must be a parsing problem of some kind.

Comment: Show a minmal complete c file with the offending header included. The header looks fine to me when I looked at it at the link location, so likely there is a missing brace or some other error confusing the parser.

Comment: @PeterSchneider There was another error `reference to ‘Window’ is ambiguous`, that was because header file had clash with namespaces included in it. So I think the problem might be with the header file

Comment: What is your compiler? Platform? Give details man

Comment: I compiled with a g++ under cygwin and had to comment in the ctor of Point in Point.h which takes 2 ints, but other than that it worked (after unpacking the fltk sources and copying the FL header directory -- as a directory -- into the main source directory).

Comment: Judging from the other post you mention I expect a name clash between other headers (X windows?). I also don't ge the narrowing warning. Most likely somebody else already used names like Window, Color etc. and has a using directive as well. Remove all `using namespace Graph_lib;` from Stroustrup's files, qualify all your names and compile again.

Comment: @PeterSchneider I qualified all the names, then tried compiling the whole program, now I am left only with the narrowing error.

Comment: .. which is a warning. Since I don't get it though, I assume that your `Color`  is not my `Color` (or Stroustrup's) ;-). [I'm off now. gl.]

Comment: @PeterSchneider compiled it with the `-Werror` flag, the program is supposed  to draw a polygon in a window, when I run the `.o` file nothing happens.

Comment: I got it working, the line `Color(int cc) :c(Fl_Color(cc)), v(visible) { }` in `Graph.h` had to be changed to `Color(unsigned int cc) :c(Fl_Color(cc)), v(visible) { }`